# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a big csv file, where the first looks like the following example. I have almost thousands of rows like this.

```
{"ts":"1542055197138.168","rs":"1920x1080","ets":"1542057356101.471","meta.mobileoptimized":"320","meta.wm_reporting_category":"no iapath","status":"not logged in","dnt":"false","cookies":"true","meta.country":"us","calltype":"ev","meta.language":"en","sa_source":"meta.iapath","meta.iapath":"no iapath","localstorage":"true","t_profile":"cisco.apps","meta.locale":"us","content_type":"no contenttype","t_load":"utag","jse":"0","meta.handheldfriendly":"true","meta.viewport":"width","loc":"http://xxxxo.xxxx.com/idp/sso.saml2","returnvisit":"true","action":"pageunloaded","utag_main_v_id":"01655cb498e600033ae6e4f5c04d0204900300410086e","locale":"en-us","linktrack":"linkpage","meta.title":"login page","breakpoint":"short","ev":"activity","viewtimer":"0","entitlement":"undefined","adobeversions":"appmeasurement","meta.accesslevel":"guest","relaystate":"s27d4add1b4c5f2eb6dcf3200ffa56a3ee30c4d133","timerseq":"0","hier1":"no iapath","title":"xxx.com login page"}
```

I'm trying to extract only the meta tags like `"title"` and `"meta.accesslevel"` with the code below. But it is giving me an error saying `"json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"`

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import json
new_names = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20']
df = pd.read_csv('metadata10.csv',names=new_names)
df1 = df ['19']
file = open('metadata3.csv',"w")
file.write('meta_title' + ',' + 'meta_description' + ',' + 'meta_url' + ',' +'meta_access_level' + '\n')##Header for file
for i in range (len(df1)):
    x = json.loads(df1[i])
    file.write(x["meta.description"] + ',')
    file.write(x["title"] + ',')
    file.write (x["title"] + ',')
    file.write (x["meta.url"] + ',')
    file.write (x["meta.accesslevel"] + '\n')


file.close()
```